# aws guardduty agent container is not in healthy state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-guardduty

I tried to setup GuardDuty Runtime Monitoring for ECS Fargate cluster, both ECS task and GuardDuty runtime coverage are in healthy state, but when I check findings section I don't see any findings, also I can see guardduty agent container is in unhealthy state. Can anyone please help me fix this.

[image]